# What must I deploy for a project that uses OpenNETCF?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, windows-ce, opennetcf, typeloadexception

I created an .exe using the OpenNETCF's SerialPort class, but when I copied the .exe to the Motorola device running Windows CE 6 and tried to run it, I got:

```
TypeLoad
Exception
File or assembly name 'OpenNETCF, Version=1.3.50123.0...or one of its dependencies was not found.
```

What file or files do I need to copy over to remedy this? Is there a way to cause Visual Studio (2003, .NET 1.1) to bundle the required bits into the .exe?

I noticed in Build | Configuration Manager that the only context I have set up is "Debug"; would changing this from Debug to Release make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Visual Studio 2003, but in 2008 you can create a Smart Device Deployment CAB, which essentially creates an installer for you, which would have a copy of all the references you need for your program to work.

Answer (score 0):

This may have been overkill, but I copied all the OpenNETCF dlls over, and the problem was solved.